# Error 404--Not Found after deploying weblogic server

Tags: server, http-status-code-404, weblogic

I am having a problem when accessing my weblogic page. (Before someone marks this as duplicate, none of the answers worked for me)

I'm getting this error when acessing my page:
[Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfvYB.png)

I've deployed the server and everything seems to be correct as shown:
[Ecplise Server deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E4BT.png)
[Weblogic console deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rwsD.png)

The thing is that I can access the http://localhost:7001/console but not the http://localhost:7001/SGES.

[Deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2lqw.png)
[Testing 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC338.png)

Any ideas?
I don't know what more images I can show to help.

Comment: At first do not provide information as images or external links. Everything must be written in your post.
Can you test your application using test points displayed in your admin console ( Deployments/Deployments table/Select your application/Testing tab)
Also share your web.xml and weblogic.xml file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KynWtN2y here's the web.xml, i've added the rest in the question

Comment: Did you set the admin server listen address to 192.168.1.72 ??
If so, your application is located at http://192.168.1.72:7001/SGES